# wp_usermeta wp_usersettings

Tags: options, user-meta

I would like to know what does these meta_value means for wp_usersettings meta_key in wp_usermeta table?

- meta_key: wp_usersettings
- meta_value: m1=o&m3=o&m0=o&m2=o

Thanks

Comment: You should mention you also posted the question here for completeness: http://groups.google.com/group/wp-hackers/browse_thread/thread/eb9ecb90f23d7f25/7a00a50558daab92?show_docid=7a00a50558daab92

Comment: I will do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user changes their admin settings; like the screen options, posts per page or moves  metaboxes around or 'hides' them, it is saved in their user settings.

So if user settings are blank - the user has never tailored their admin environment.

Aside:
(I use this to great advantage in one of my plugins to simplify the backend initially but allow users to 'grow'.  IE - a 'template' user can setup how they would like the admin environment to look by closing meta boxes, changing columns displayed etc.  Then when a new user is created, i have the template user settings copied over to new user to present a simplified admin backend.  The new user can then add back features as they learn more.  I love it!)